# How to use alfresco java API to submit form values

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, java

I have developed one spring based java web application. In my project it is requirement to use alfresco as a CMS. For this I want to integrate this application with alfresco. So I decided to use alfresco java API's.
http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/

But I am not getting how to use those API's to complete backend work of my web application. Suppose I would like to submit one form having user name & password fields in it. After click on submit button how can I handle request in backend so it will use Alfresco java API to process request and store details in database.

I have to do many operations in my project like upload file, play with documents, Submit different forms. view those forms etc.

My first question is am I going in right direction by using alfresco java API's. if yes then how can use those API? is there any other way to do this?

Any help would be appreciate!!!

Thanks in Advance,
Kailas Salunke.

Comment: So you've decided on Alfresco as your CMS, good choice! Next I recommend you follow the developer series tutorials http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series to get to know what you can do. Beyond that the style of question here is difficult to answer. If you have a specific issue or would like us to recommend a solution for a specific requirement then that we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on my experience, Alfresco is an excellent ECM but not suitable for being a CMS.

Apart from that, it is difficult to give suggestions, starting from the very general overview you have given, but things like user name and password have little to do with an ECM and storing of data in a database.

You have two options available.

One involve using the [Web Content Management Quick Start](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start_Installation_and_Configuration), it's a Spring Surf app you can (not easily in my opinion) customize for your needs.

The other solutions, if you have an existing web app, rather than develop your own API have a look at [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services), I have put a simple wikipedia explanation, you can dig further from there.

Then, when you are ready, have a look at [Alfresco CMIS](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS) first, and the most used Java API for doing CMIS call, which is [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/project/cmis.html)

CMIS, in its intent, guarantee that Alfresco could be replaced with any other CMIS compliant ECM. You can easily integrate Apache Chemistry in your Spring app.

Comment: Thank you so much Leonardo !!!. Hope this documents link provides me gateway to my probles.